# Использовать ли тег <dialog>?

Tags: html, dialog

Использовать ли тег `<dialog>`?

Или использовать другое модальное окно?

Например написать самому или взять готовое например в bootstrap.

Всё ли браузеры поддерживают `<dialog>`?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/dialog поддержка 93.76%

Comment: Если знаете и понимаете где и как использовать, то использовать обязательно. На сегодняшний день, все актуальные версии популярных браузеров поддерживают этот элемент. Семантика, accessibility...